# Open iFrame of Links in Map Feature Data in MapBox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a MapBox map of points, with a column called "iframe_link", where there's a different link for each point. I made an iframe that works for one page, but I want to open an iframe for each point.

I'm using the following line of code to try to open the links as an iframe, and it's not working:

```
'<iframe src="e.features[0].properties.iframe_link"</iframe>'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to insert the value of e.features[0].properties.iframe_link into a string in JavaScript? If so, you have to concatenate the strings like so:

`'<iframe src="' + e.features[0].properties.iframe_link + '"</iframe>'`